# Host key formats

Tags: ssh, public-key, ssh-keygen

I understand what host keys are and how the public host key on a server is used to identify the identity of the host to avoid a man in the middle attack. As per my understanding, the host keys are generated using either of the rsa/dsa/ecdsa/ed25519 algorithms. My goal is to verify if a given string is in the right format of a host keys. Is verifying if the format is in a valid OpenSSH rsa/dsa/ecdsa/ed25519  sufficient. I am not sure if I am missing any other formats. Any documentation would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -l` might be useful?

Comment: That is just used to generate the key ; not sure how that would help me verify all the supported formats

Comment: `ssh-keygen -l` tries to generate the fingerprint of a key and should fail if the format of the key isn't proper.